# Error: File "figure_name" not found - Texmaker on VMware virtual machine

Tags: errors, texmaker

Today I experienced a very strange error: I've a tex file which works perfectly on the physical machine (I'm using Texmaker). The same file doesn't work on the virtual machine of VMware; if I remove the pieces:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{fig1}
\caption{Bla bla bla.}
\end{figure}
```

it works, instead, when I use the figures, it doesn't work. How can I fix this problem?

The folder where I put the figures is always the same (it's inside the folder where there is the tex file):

```
\graphicspath{ {Immagini/} }
```